# Can not connect to SQL Server database file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, connection-string

In the output directory of my solution there's a folder called `Storage`. In this folder is a database file `Comments.sdf` with no password.

Now I want to connect to this database by the following code:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=\Storage\Comments.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

The line `connection.Open();` throws an exception.

I only have the german error-message:

> Netzwerkbezogener oder instanzspezifischer Fehler beim Herstellen
>   einer Verbindung mit SQL Server. Der Server wurde nicht gefunden, oder
>   auf ihn kann nicht zugegriffen werden. Überprüfen Sie, ob der
>   Instanzname richtig ist und ob SQL Server Remoteverbindungen zulässt.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Verbindungszeichenfolge
>   ungültig)

In english it's like:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   it can not be accessed. Verify that the instance name is correct and
>   that SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is invalid)

Is there anything wrong with my connection string or do I have to set some properties at the database file?

Comment: You do realize you need a sql-server running to actually connect to that file, right?

Comment: If you are using sql server compact, which I believe is the case here, no running sql server instance is required.

Comment: Could it be that the problem is that I've create the databasefile with sql-server 2008 r2 and implement the solution in VS2012?

Comment: @Tarec: **NO** he does not! It's a SQL Server **Compact Edition** file - this is a stand-alone database file, just a few DLLs needed, **NO SERVER** installation needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string is specifing an invalid path to the database file.  Simply remove the first /

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=Storage\Comments.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
SqlCeConnectionconnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

be sure to reference System.Data.SqlServerCe

Comment: No, this doesn't solve the problem. I also tried a absolute path, and it still doesn't work

Comment: I received the same message

Comment: I have updated my post, add a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe and change your connection to SqlCeConnection

Comment: Ok this solved my problem. But now I get another exception: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeInvalidDatabaseFormatException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: Sounds like you have a version mismatch between client and file format

Comment: Yes. But I can't create a database-file in the sql-server 2012